# How to decrypt private key and export decrypted using CryptoAPI in C++

Tags: c++, cryptography, cryptoapi

we are using GRPC in C++ and it's requesting a pem encoded certificate chain and private key. However this private key must not be password protected (as it has no support for it). However our product historically allowed to use PFX that can contain encrypted private key. I figured out a way how to export a private key from PFX into PEM using chain of functions

```
PFXImportCertStore
CertEnumCertificatesInStore
CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey
CryptGetUserKey
CryptExportKey
CryptEncodeObjectEx
CryptBinaryToStringA
```

but as my understanding this would return a PEM where private key is password protected which I cannot use (if pfx contained password protected private key).  I need to remove the password protection.

Thank you